# iterate through php array from custom sql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I did a custom JOIN query to my db and returned an array of all the info I need but I can't display it. If i `var_dump($query);` I can see all the info but when I do this I get nothing?

```
orders = $wpdb->get_results($query);
<?php foreach ($orders as $order) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $date; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $order['order_first_name']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $order['order_last_name']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $order['contact_email']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $order['contact_phone']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $order['order_address']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $order['order_state']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $order['order_zip']; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

If I dump one order like `<?php foreach ($orders as $order) {  var_dump($order)}?>` I get this

```
object(stdClass)#2300 (11) { ["order_contact_id"]=> string(5) "67378" ["order_date"]=> string(17) "20160129T15:23:20" ["order_contact"]=> string(13) "XXXXXX" ["order_first_name"]=> string(6) "XXXXXX" ["order_last_name"]=> string(6) "XXXXXX" ["contact_email"]=> string(23) "XXXXXX" ["contact_phone"]=> string(17) "XXXXXX" ["order_address"]=> string(24) "XXXXXX" ["order_city"]=> string(8) "XXXXXX" ["order_state"]=> string(2) "CO" ["order_zip"]=> string(5) "80241" }
```

Comment: Any PHP object can be converted to an array by 'cast'ing it. i.e. `<?php foreach ( 
 (array) $orders as $order) ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access a object like an array. Try this:

```
<?php
$orders = $wpdb->get_results($query);
foreach ($orders as $order) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $date; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $order->order_first_name; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $order->order_last_name; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $order->contact_email; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $order->contact_phone; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $order->order_address; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $order->order_state; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $order->order_zip; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Good call. I didnt see that it was dumping an object. Thanks!

Comment: Lol thanks, sometimes it is the simplest things that trip us up. Even the most experienced devs fall victim to that.